# Remove duplicates from a dictionary with object, based on a property in the Value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

How to remove all duplicates with a LINQ statement from a dictionary looking like this:

```
Dictionary<Type1, Type2>()
```

Type2 contains a string property ID. I want to remove all entries that has the same ID

Comment: the concept of a dictionary is that Type1/Key contains the unique ID

Comment: I want to remove all entries that has the same Value.id, and keep for only one of them

Comment: What are the criteria to choose which of the duplicates to keep? If we have two entries: <1,"abc"> and <2, "abc">, do we remove the one with key 1 or 2?

Comment: So just to clarify. You want to keep 1 key+value for each duplicated ID inside the value, it's arbitrary which key+value from those duplicates to keep, and it's OK to build a new dictionary with the kept items, instead of actually removing anything from the first dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the dictionary on a specific field you want to, and then get the first value matching (or all):

```
Dictionary<Type1, Type2> d = new Dictionary<Type1, Type2>();

var entriesToBeRemoved = d.GroupBy(x => x.Value.SomeId)
                         .SelectMany(x => x.Skip(1))
                         .ToList()
                         ;

foreach (var kvp in entriesToBeRemoved)
{
    d.Remove(kvp.Key);
}
```

Or if you don't care to create a new dictionary for the results:

```
Dictionary<Type1, Type2> d = new Dictionary<Type1, Type2>();

var d2 = d.GroupBy(x => x.Value.SomeId)
          .ToDictionary(x => x.First().Key, x => x.First().Value)
          ;
```

Comment: because  he need a distinct on  values while preserving keys

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks! (Looks too complicated tho :) ) Also I figured out that it needs to be g.First().Key, instead of g.Key

Comment: Shouldn't that be `.ToDictionary(x => x.First().Key, x => x.First().Value)`?  Otherwise `d2` is `Dictionary<Type1, string>`.

Comment: @juharr: That is possible too, but now I take the `Key` from `IGrouping`, which is effectively the dictionaries `Value`.

Comment: And how will knowing which values to remove help?

Comment: @PatrickHofman The `Key` of the `IGrouping` is `x.Value.SomeId`, not `x.Value`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: No, it takes the first key in the dictionary matching the specific `IdField` and takes the entire value of it.

Comment: @juharr: Indeed, realized it later on you were right. Fixed.

Comment: And how does this help? There can be many keys that have values with the same ID, you're grabbing only the first from each group.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: "I want to remove all entries that has the same ID" > it does that by grouping on that field. All others are 'removed'.

Comment: How does this remove the duplicates from the original dictionary?

Comment: OK, so you're not actually *removing* anything from the first dictionary, you're creating a new dictionary. I guess we're still in "what does the OP really want" territory then.

Comment: And can't you simply do `x.First()`, shouldn't that be a KeyValuePair already?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen `ToDictionary` needs to know what the key and value are.  You cannot just give it a `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: Okay guys. Thanks for the feedback. I think I have resolved all of the mentioned bugs. Any suggestions left?

Comment: The deletion code just edited in will still only remove one key+value from the original dictionary, so that is still not right. You need to collect *all* keys from that group, except the first (since we don't have any better criteria for choosing which one to keep).

Comment: For the `entriesToBeRemoved` code, why build a dictionary?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Right. Fixed.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Still doesn't work. You are removing entries from the dictionary while you are iterating it. You need to force the LINQ query before the `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work exactly as you required:

```
var removables =
    dict
        .ToLookup(x => x.Value.ID, x => x.Key)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Skip(1))
        .ToArray();

foreach (var key in removables)
{
    dict.Remove(key);
}
```

Comment: If you do a `ToList` instead of `ToArray` you can employ the `ForEach` method on `List<T>` to do the removal as part of the single statement.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - There's also a `Array.ForEach(...)` method. I was tempted to use that one, but I get the feeling that a simple `foreach` would be better for the OP in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the great help in my answer. +1 to you.